# What does char (*)[20] in C mean?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I know that the below code is not valid since `%s` expects an argument of type `char *` but I have given an argument of type `char **`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct employee
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float salary;
};
int main(void)
{
    struct employee e;
    scanf("%19s", &e.name);//Invalid line
    printf("%s", e.name);
}
```

But I get a different warning:

`./ Playground / file0.  c: In function main:.  / Playground / file0.  c: 11: 15: warning: format '% s' expects argument of type' char * ', but argument2 has type char (*) [20]' [- Wformat =] 11 |  scanf ("% 195", & e. name);  |  char (*) [20] char *`

I am pretty much sure that `char **` and `char (*)[20]` are somewhat equivalent but not sure how they are.

`char **`: pointer to a pointer to a char.

`char (*)[20]`: An array of pointers to a char. — Not sure if I am totally right here.

I am not getting it. How are they equivalent? Please enlighten me.

Comment: @user3121023 Please read the question again.

Comment: `char (*)[20]` first the parenthesis, then right to left: <pointer to> <array of 20> <char>. Compare with `char *[20]` (no parenthesis, read right to left): <array of 20> <pointer to> <char>.

Comment: Some compilers are pickier than others in this regard. However, you can use `e.name` as an argument to `scanf()` for the same reason that you can use `e.name` as an argument to `printf()`. You don't need `&`.

Comment: Your invalid line should be changed to `scanf("%19s", e.name);` or `scanf("%19s", &e.name[0]);` because `scanf`'s `%s` specifier expects a `char *` argument. (For `e.name`, the `char [20]` lvalue will decay to a `char *`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `char (*)[20]` is read as "pointer to array of size 20 of `char`.  It is *not* an array of pointers to `char`.

An array (of size 20) of pointers to `char` would be `char *[20]`.  Because this is an array, it can *decay* to a pointer to the first element of the array.  Since the array's elements are of type `char *`, such a pointer would have type `char **`.

Going back to your code, `e.name` has type `char [20]`, i.e. array of size 20 of `char`.  From there it follows that `&e.name` has type `char (*)[20]`, i.e. pointer to array of size 20 of `char`.

Comment: Why the array's elements are of type ```char *```?

Comment: @NirajRaut In `e.name`, they're not.  They're of type `char`. In which case are you referring to?

Comment: You wrote, *Since the array's elements are of type char *, such a pointer would have type char **.* I didn't understand it.

Comment: @NirajRaut That's if you had a variable of type `char *[20]`.  That's different from `char (*)[20]`

Comment: One last question — Is ```char (*)[]``` exactly the same as ```char**```? Is it different in different structures?

Comment: @NirajRaut They are not exactly the name.  One is a pointer to an array of `char`, while the other is a pointer to a pointer to `char`.  `char *[]` (an array of pointers to `char`) is not exactly the same either, but it can decay to `char **`.

Comment: But they are the same when used in function parameters, right?

Comment: @NirajRaut As a function parameter `char **` and `char *[]` are the same, since arrays as parameters are automatically converted to pointers.